# python: repeating a word after a word for a twitch bot

Tags: python, bots, echo, twitch, mirror

I've been trying to create a pyramid command in twitch chat for about 2 weeks now however I'm struggling on how to repeat a word after a specific keyword for example if someone types +pyramid (emote) in chat I want to be able to repeat that specific message after they type +pyramid, im not sure how i can start to do this because I've only found out how to replace words when they are defined e.g replace test with yo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to tell what you have tried so far and where did you fail.

Answer (score 1):

you could replace "+pyramid" with "" (nothing) and that would leave you with your emote. Now you can do a for loop and times the string by the iterator variable to make a pyramid, printing on each loop.